# Can you access methods from a ROOT object when you pass the object as an argument to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, root-framework

Excuse my ignorance, but I am new to C++ and ROOT and I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong.

What I am trying to do is to write a function that returns the bin locations of n-peaks in a histogram. The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include "TROOT.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TH1.h"
#include "TF1.h"

using namespace std;

int *peak_counter1d(TH1F *histogram,int peak_num,int threshold = 5,int display = 0){
  if(display == 1){
    TCanvas *look = new TCanvas("look","look",500,400);
    histogram->Draw();
  }
  int total_bins = histogram->GetNBinsX();
  double peak_bins[peak_num];
  peak_bins[0] = histogram->GetMaximumBin();
  int counter = 1;
  int *check_array; // to put previously found peak bins
  while(counter < peak_num){
    double peak = threshold;
    double peak_loc = -500;
    check_array = new int[counter];
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
      check_array[i] = peak_bins[i]; // fills the array with previously found peak bins
    }
    for(int i=0; i<total_bins; i++){
      if(peak < histogram->GetBinContent(i)){ 
        bool exists = find(begin(check_array),end(checkarray),i); // makes sure this is a peak we haven't already found
        if(!exists){
          peak = histogram->GetBinContent(i);
          peak_loc = i;
        }
      }
    }
    peak_bins[counter] = peak_loc;
    counter ++;
  }
  delete[] check_array;

  return peak_bins;
}

void testing(){
  gROOT->Reset();
  TH1F *histo = new TH1F("histo","try",100,0,10);
  TF1 *f1 = new TF1("f1","exp(-x/10)*sin(x)*sin(x)",0,10);
  double val;
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    val = f1->Eval(i/10.0);
    //cout << i << "\t" << i/100.0 << "\t" << val << endl;
    histo->SetBinContent(i,val);
  }

  int *peak_bins;
  peak_bins = peak_counter1d(histo,3,5,1);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout << i << "\t" << *(peak_bins+i) << endl;
  }
}
```

When I execute this code in ROOT, I get the following:

```
root [] .x testing.cpp
Error: Can't call TH1F::GetNBinsX() in current scope testing.cpp:15:
Possible candidates are...
(in TH1F)
(in TH1)
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
```

I think this is a problem with getting access to object methods inside of a function, because when I call the histo->GetNBinsX() method in the testing() function, I get no problems. However I do not know.

Thank you, and if I am doing other disastrously horrible coding practices, please let me know.

Comment: `double peak_bins[peak_num];`  You are returning a pointer to this local array.  Returning pointers to local variables is undefined behavior.  You also have potential memory leak here: `double peak_bins[peak_num];`  Use `std::vector` for these issues, not raw pointers.

Comment: Side note. I was unaware that c++ interpreters existed. And ya, returning pointers to local variables is bad, mmkay?

Answer (score 0):

It was already pointed out that one cannot return the address of a local variable, that will be destroyed when the function ends.

Your other problem was about:

```
histo->GetNbinsX()
```

not working. I tried to call it both in main and in a subroutine of a script: it works perfectly for me, with the current ROOT version. In the question, you misspelled as `GetNBinsX` (that, yes, would be more coherent with the camel case policy). Perhaps...?

Anyway, I'm sure you would be pleased to know that ROOT has a quite smart 1D peak-searching algorithm ready for use: look for [the TSpectrum class](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTSpectrum.html).

Answer (score -1):

There are various issues with your code.

The most glaring is this one:

```
int *peak_counter1d(TH1F *histogram,int peak_num,int threshold = 5,int display = 0)
{
    //...
    double peak_bins[peak_num];
    //...
    return peak_bins;
}
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable.  Returning pointers to local variables is *undefined behavior*.

The next issue is this:

```
  int *check_array; // to put previously found peak bins
  while(counter < peak_num)
  {
      //...
      check_array = new int[counter];
  }
  delete[] check_array;
```

You have a potential memory leak since you are looping without ever deallocating `check_array`.  The other issue is that if that loop never executes, you are calling `delete []` on an uninitialized variable.

The next issue is this:

```
int * peak_counter1d(...)
{
    double peak_bins[peak_num];
    //...
    return peak_bins;
}
```

Even if you could safely return a pointer to a local variable, your function returns an int*, but you're returning a `double *`.

The next issue is this:

```
TCanvas *look = new TCanvas("look","look",500,400);
```

You are allocating `look`, but you never deallocate it, or even use it.

You also do the same thing in `main`:

```
 TH1F *histo = new TH1F("histo","try",100,0,10);
  TF1 *f1 = new TF1("f1","exp(-x/10)*sin(x)*sin(x)",0,10);
```

C++ is not Java.  You don't have to create objects using `new`.

```
TH1F histo("histo","try",100,0,10);
  TF1 f1("f1","exp(-x/10)*sin(x)*sin(x)",0,10);
```

Except for the last issue, overall these issues can be fixed if you resorted to using `std::vector`, and not use `new[]` to create dynamic arrays.

Applying these changes, the code should look something like this (not compiled):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include "TROOT.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TH1.h"
#include "TF1.h"

using namespace std;

vector<int> peak_counter1d(TH1F *histogram,int peak_num,int threshold = 5,int display = 0)
{
  if(display == 1)
  {
    // TCanvas *look = new TCanvas("look","look",500,400);
     histogram->Draw();
  }
  int total_bins = histogram->GetNBinsX();
  vector<int> peak_bins(peak_num);
  peak_bins[0] = histogram->GetMaximumBin();
  int counter = 1;
  vector<int> check_array; // to put previously found peak bins
  while(counter < peak_num){
    double peak = threshold;
    double peak_loc = -500;
    check_array.resize(counter);
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
      check_array[i] = peak_bins[i]; // fills the array with previously found peak bins
    }
    for(int i=0; i<total_bins; i++){
      if(peak < histogram->GetBinContent(i)){ 
        bool exists = find(begin(check_array),end(checkarray),i); // makes sure this is a peak we haven't already found
        if(!exists){
          peak = histogram->GetBinContent(i);
          peak_loc = i;
        }
      }
    }
    peak_bins[counter] = peak_loc;
    counter ++;
  }
  return peak_bins;
}

void testing(){
  gROOT->Reset();
  TH1F histo("histo","try",100,0,10);
  TF1 f1("f1","exp(-x/10)*sin(x)*sin(x)",0,10);
  double val;
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    val = f1.Eval(i/10.0);
    //cout << i << "\t" << i/100.0 << "\t" << val << endl;
    histo.SetBinContent(i,val);
  }

  vector<int> peak_bins = peak_counter1d(&histo,3,5,1);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout << i << "\t" << peak_bins[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I was returning a pointer to a local variable. I also didn't realize the vector library was so useful.  I do have two questions regarding this however. 

In main, you changed TH1F *histo = new TH1F(...) to TH1F histo(...). However, in the function above, you left the first parameter as a pointer. I would have to change if from peak_counter1d(TH1F *histogram,...) to peak_counter1d(TH1F histogram,...) right? 

In addition, the original problem of getting GetNBinsX() is still there.

Comment: Note that in `main`, I passed the address of the variable, so the pointer is still valid as the first argument.